# SQL - Associate one record from a table to the ones of another only one time

Tags: sql

I have this 2 tables:
Position/Article

```
+--------------+---------------+------------------+---------+
| Col Position | Col IdArticle | Col ExpiringDate | Col xxx |
+--------------+---------------+------------------+---------+
|         1001 |           123 | 31/12/2018       | abc     |
|         1002 |           123 | 31/11/2018       | cdf     |
|         1003 |           123 | 31/12/2019       | ghi     |
|         2001 |           456 | 31/12/2018       | lko     |
|         2002 |           456 | 31/01/2018       | oki     |
|         2003 |           456 | 12/12/2019       | oono    |
+--------------+---------------+------------------+---------+
```

CustomerOrder/Article

```
+-------------------+---------------+
| Col CustomerOrder | Col IdArticle |
+-------------------+---------------+
| A                 |           123 |
| A                 |           456 |
| B                 |           123 |
| B                 |           456 |
| C                 |           123 |
| C                 |           456 |
+-------------------+---------------+
```

I want to get, for each `CustomerOrder` and `IdArticle` one position for the `IdArticle` (each position must not be repeated) *and extra columns from the table Position/Article*

This is the result I would like to have:

```
+--------------+---------------+--------------+------------------+---------+
| Col Customer | Col IdArticle | Col Position | Col ExpiringDate | Col xxx |
+--------------+---------------+--------------+------------------+---------+
| A            |           123 |         4001 | xxxx             | aaaa    |
| A            |           456 |         2001 | aaaa             | kkkkk   |
| B            |           123 |         1002 | bbbbb            | loojj   |
| B            |           456 |         2002 | cccc             | jokjio  |
| C            |           123 |         1003 | dddd             | hijooi  |
| C            |           456 |         2003 | eeee             | ookii   |
+--------------+---------------+--------------+------------------+---------+
```

I've tried with joins and `row_number` but was not able to come to a solution; it's probably much more easier than I think.

Comment: looking to you updated  value  ..   think that with flat sql your question can't be solved ... could be with procedural  .. code  ..

Comment: Are you thinking about a WHILE?

Comment: not only while  .. you should scan for main query  ... select for a value  .. update for reverse  the value and  restart  .... seems  not easy for me  ..

Comment: May put in var table, use the value and than delete the row ? the cycle finishes when no more rows are in the table ?